# Symbolic power of a prime ideal is primary

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $S$ a multiplicatively closed
subset of $A$. For any ideal $\mathfrak a$, let $S(\mathfrak a)$ denote the inverse image of $S^{−1}\mathfrak a$ under the localization map $\varphi: A → S^{−1}A$. We denote $\mathfrak p^{(n)}:= S_{\mathfrak p}(\mathfrak p^n)$ where $S_{\mathfrak p}:= A \setminus\mathfrak p$.

> Prove that $\mathfrak p^{(n)} $ is a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal, and if $\mathfrak p^n$ has a primary decomposition, then $\mathfrak p^{(n)}$ is a $\mathfrak p$-primary component. (Atiyah and Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, Chapter 4, Exercise 13 i) and ii).)

My approach: to prove that $\mathfrak p^{(n)}: = \varphi^{-1}(S_{\mathfrak p}^{-1}\mathfrak p^n)$ is primary. Let $xy \in \mathfrak p^{(n)}, x \notin \mathfrak p^{(n)} $. I need to show that there exists an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y^m \in \mathfrak p^{(n)}$. From $xy \in \mathfrak p^{(n)}, x \notin \mathfrak p^{(n)}$ it follows $\varphi(x)\varphi(y) \in S_{\mathfrak p}^{-1}\mathfrak p^n, \varphi(x) \notin S_{\mathfrak p}^{-1}\mathfrak p^n$. At this step I do not know how to show that $\exists m\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\varphi(y)^m \in S_{\mathfrak p}^{-1}\mathfrak p^n$.

Please give me some hints. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A contraction of a primary ideal is primary.
- Let $Q$ be the $\mathfrak p$-primary component of $\mathfrak p^n$. Both $Q$ and $\mathfrak p^{(n)}$ are $\mathfrak p$-primary ideals, so you can check the equality locally at $\mathfrak p$; they all equal to $\mathfrak p^nR_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: I think $p^n$ is not a primary ideal. So the contraction of $p^n$ is not primary.

Comment: $p^n$ is not in general, but $p^n R_p$ is since its radical is the maximal ideal.

Comment: What is $p^nR_p$. I use notion in Atiyah book, I don't know about your notation.

Comment: $IR_p$ is the extension of an $R$-ideal $I$ under the map $R \to R_p$.